# testfor wooden planks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a custom achievement, here is what I have tried

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {Inventory:[{tag:{display:{Name:"planks"}}}]}
/testfor @p[r=10] {Inventory:[{tag:{display:{Name:"minecraft:planks"}}}]}
```

I did have a wooden plank in my inventory. I am using 1.10.

Comment: Don't use `testfor` for this.  It's almost certainly not the right command for the job; you probably want to use `scoreboard` tags instead.  If you weren't planning to use `testfor` in you project, then don't use it in your question.  It encourages others to use it when there are probably better options open to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display name is not the ID of the item, it's the custom name shown on the tooltip. The ID is saved in the `id` tag at the root of the item data:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:planks"}]}
```